# Applying op to Images before sending to Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to use Tensorboard to show progress of my network as it learns. 
I am training an autoencoder, so I send the input image , and the image after that input image has been processed by the auto encoder.

(this is slightly over simplified, and I am actually doing more stuff, so please give a generalisable solution)

I am using `feed_dict` to input images. These images are already normalised using ImageNet's mean and std. So my TF graph gets these normalised images.

In order to have my images visible , I have to unnormalise them , so this is what I do :

```py
def tensor_to_img_op(tensor):
    with tf.variable_scope("",reuse=True):
        t = tensor*tf.convert_to_tensor([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]) + tf.convert_to_tensor([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
        return tf.clip_by_value(t,0,1)
```

Then , to be able to send them to the image summary, I call the `op` created by the above function to each of my tensors , like so :

```py
tf.summary.image('tensorA',tensor_to_img_op(tensorA),max_outputs=1)
tf.summary.image('tensorB',tensor_to_img_op(tensorB),max_outputs=1)
tf.summary.image('tensorC',tensor_to_img_op(tensorC),max_outputs=1)
tf.summary.image('tensorD',tensor_to_img_op(tensorD),max_outputs=1)
```

The problem with this approach is that 4 ops are created, and just 1 could have sufficed.

Inspecting the graph shows that to be true:

[image]

This to me, doesn't look like the right solution, as logically , its the same operation  , but applied to different tensors.

What is the most tensorflow solution to achieve what I want  ?

Comment: Can't you add the op once and slice the result into multiple summaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the function once, and feed its 4D tensor [N,W,H,D] assembled from tensors {A ... D}. You may have to make sure the multiplication and addition are being broadcast properly over the first dimension but I believe in general they should follow numpy rules [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
tf.summary.image('tensor',tensor_to_img_op(tensorD),max_outputs=N)
```

since summary.image can process 4D tensors.

Comment: I would like each of the images in a separate location, thats why I dont want to concatenate everything in one op